# How to use CSS' "rotateX()" with jQuery's animate() on multiple elements with delay

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

I'm working on a page layout with multiple hexagonal divs (simple tutorial for basic use is available from *jtauber* on github) disposed in three rows (for now).

I want it to have only the top left hexagon visible, while the others are rotated on the X axis so they're not visible, and that when I click on the top-left hexagon, all the others start rotating "3D-like" one after the other at regular interval, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/76q2j/10/ (in this exemple, all are visible and `rotateX()` is implemented on `:hover`in CSS.

So far, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="hex_grid">
    <!-- ROW 01 -->
    <div class="hex_row impair">
        <div id="hex0101" class="hex">
        <div class="part top"></div>
        <div class="part middle"></div>
        <div class="part bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hex0102" class="hex">
        <div class="part top"></div>
        <div class="part middle"></div>
        <div class="part bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hex0103" class="hex">
        <div class="part top"></div>
        <div class="part middle"></div>
        <div class="part bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

...and so on.

The CSS that "hides"/rotateX the divs from the start is this:

```
.hex:not(#hex0101){
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

And finally, the IDEAL jQuery for animating the whole thing would be this, or something similar:

```
$("#hex0101").click(function(event) {
    $('.hex:not("#hex0101")').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100*i).animate({transform: 'rotateX(90deg)'});
    });
});
```

BUT, after many, many trials and googling, I found out here that jQuery `.animate()` apparently does not support CSS3 `transforms` yet.

I managed to get the hexagons to appear one after the other by simply using any other type of transform, like

```
$(this).delay(100*i).animate({transform: 'skew(100px)'});
```

...although the transformation doesn't really ocurr and I don't know why for the moment, they just pop up.

Since I couldn't get CSS' `transform: rotateX()` to play nice with jQuery's `animate()`, I thought maybe adding a class with CSS transition would solve it, but as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/76q2j/13/ I came across two problems:

1. The animation doesn't really look as nice as it does with CSS `:hover` (or maybe is it just me...)
2. It applies the extra class to all hexagons at the same time instead of one after another like I would've thought

**Bottom line, or DL;DR,** I'd like to know if someone knows of a jQuery plugin that lets you combine jQuery and "advanced" CSS3 `transforms` or if there's a simpler/more practical/just plain correct way to apply an extra class to one div at a time via `each(function(i){...})`.

Any help is highly appreciated! And if something's not clear, I'll add more info, I slept very little last night so my brain's a little fuzzy...

Comment: If you do decide to use a plugin for this (though I'm not necessarily saying it's needed), I'd recommend Transit http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/. It does an awesome job at making CSS based transitions really simple.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! EDIT: it looks very promising!

Comment: Actually, that was exactly what I was looking for! Super simple, super effective! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that precisely what you wanted, but here's something :

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76q2j/25/)

In short you don't need jQuery as CSS3 transitions can be easily triggered by JS simply by changing the actual value with :

```
elem.style.property = 'value'
```

That said you can get a list of all you elements with " getElementsByClassName " and iterate through all of them (skipping the first, thus starting i at 1) then changing the value.

Since you don't want all of them to flip at the same time I simply put the code in an interval and used the function that is called to increment i.

You also have to make sure that you stop the interval and remove the " onclick " event once all the elements have been processed.

Comment: I just realised I completely forgot about your :hover. Here's an edited version, strangely the event triggers only on the bottom half, I'm investigating.

http://jsfiddle.net/76q2j/23/

Comment: Googles gave me an [answer](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/possible-webkit-bug-hover-area-on-items-that-are-inline-block-and-rotated/).
Fixed it somewhat.
I'm using chrome, further testing in other browsers is required.

Comment: Merci! I was looking for jQuery since that's what I'm more confortable with, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @BlakeMann actually suggested a very simple plugin (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) that does exactly what I was expecting from jQuery's `animate()`. I think it's better for people like me who prefer sticking with jQuery than dealing with intervals and such.

Comment: In that case submit your own answer to your question and explain it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a more complete answer for now. I tried the [Transit jQuery plugin](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) by Rico Sta Cruz (rstacruz on github) and it works great for manipulating 2D and 3D CSS transforms, but using jQuery to do so has caused the `:hover`on the hexagons to be restrained to the top half. I don't know how to explain that better...

Comment: Basically, using pure JS, the whole hexagon can be hovered because it's done via CSS but using the plugin, I can't hover an hexagon unless the cursor is over the upper part, like some other element was blocking the bottom 2/3.I'll try targetting `$(".hex:children")`on hover but I changed the way my hexagons were made so I'm not able to test it right now.